# ob-ipython error message while evaluating SRC block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, ipython, jupyter

I am getting this error when executing any source ipython block such as this one:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ipython :session :results output drawer

# Compute areas and colors
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 150
r = 2 * np.random.rand(N)
theta = 2 * np.pi * np.random.rand(N)
area = 200 * r**2
colors = theta

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
c = ax.scatter(theta, r, c=colors, s=area, cmap='hsv', alpha=0.75)

#+END_SRC
```

> There was a fatal error trying to process the request. See *ob-ipython-debug*

ob-ipython-debug:

```
 File "/Users/USER/.emacs.d/elpa/ob-ipython-20180113.929/client.py", line 1, in <module>
    import jupyter_client as client
ImportError: No module named jupyter_client
```

I don't know what can be wrong (I have all the necessary dependencies requires like `ipython`, `jupyter`, `python`, and obviously `ob-ipython`). Any help appreciated.

Thanks, 
EG

Comment: BTW, the ob-ipython-debug says: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/USER/.emacs.d/elpa/ob-ipython-20180113.929/client.py", line 1, in <module>
    import jupyter_client as client
ImportError: No module named jupyter_client"

Comment: Can you post the part of the `.emacs` related with your babel configuration?

Comment: Sure, but I don't think it's related to babel (org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((matlab . t)
   (python . t)
   (ipython . t)
   ;(emacs-lisp . t)
   ;(shell . t)
   ;(matlab . t)
   ;(dot . t)
   ;(R . t)
   ))

Comment: [Sorry, I don't seem to know how to format code in stackexchange]

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I've checked and the file IS there. I tried to give execution permission to the file... but I'm still getting the error. I also have the line `(require 'ob-ipython)` in the `.emacs` file.

Comment: Thanks, it's very annoying! I also have the require line in my init file. Let's see if someone can help.

Comment: Maybe we need to specify the path to the client? How to do this?

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein: re. formatting code - just indent everything by four spaces and paste it in. You should edit the question and do that with your original code as well: images of code are frowned upon.

Comment: @Nick, I can't seem to be able to edit my comments.

Comment: To edit comments, I believe you need to do it quickly (within 5 minutes) and you have to have enough reputation (but I don't know how much is enough). But you should be able to edit your question.

Comment: Understood, thanks! I have included the comment in my question for completion.

Comment: But you deleted the image of the code without adding the text of the code. But in any case, it's clear you are missing the `jupyter_client` module.

Comment: Yes, the code was just an example. I just added a short sample code.

Answer (score 1):

On my system, this error happens because my jupyter installation is based on `python3`, while `python-shell-interpreter` in emacs is `python`. This can be fixed by running `M-S-: (setq python-shell-interpreter "python3")`. You can put this command in your init file if you only use python3.

For those on Debian/Ubuntu, this can also be fixed by installing python2.7 version of jupyter by running `apt install python-jupyter-client python-jupyter-console`. Note that Debian packages `jupyter-*` are all python3 based.

Another way to deal with this issue is by using python environments. If you're using Anaconda and installed jupyter through it, running `conda activate` before you start emacs should point your shell's python to conda's version.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I followed the instruction, but alas I keep getting the problem. "ImportError: No module named jupyter_client". I will never be able to use ipython :((